# URL for authenticated user edit own webform submission

Tags: webforms, users, redirection

I have checked the "authenticated user" option in "content">"nameOfMyWebform">"Webform"(tab)>"Form settings">"Submission access">"Roles that can submit this webform".

My problem is that I don't know the link (URL) to access to the edit submission page like an authenticated user. I don't know if it is configurable and I have tried with many URL...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with the [Permissions per Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_per_webform) module and the URL /node/nid/submission/sid/edit

Answer (score 0):

BTW, there is a brand new "Redirect to login when access denied to submission" setting which does exactly what it says it does in the latest dev release. (/admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/settings/submissions)